# windows desktop new folder c++

Tags: winapi, com, icons, desktop, windows-shell

Purpose :
New folder creation function in Windows Explorer (Desktop)
(Icon coordinate setting + label correction)

I am wondering how to create a new folder like Windows Explorer (Desktop).

I want to know the same function as "Right click on desktop → New → Folder".

What I want is to make it to specific coordinates.

++ It would be better if you could also modify the label.

This is how I did it.

CreateDirectory → FindWindow (Desktop Listview) → SendMessage (LVM_SETITEMPOSITION)

But when I do `CreateDirectory` it appears too slow on the desktop.
(Default 1000ms or more)

So I tried `SHChangeNotify` but it appears slow.

That source code functions to move the mouse to a specific location on the desktop and press a shortcut to create a folder with that coordinate.
However, I can see the folder appearing slow and moving (`SendMessage (LVM_SETITEMPOSITION)`).

```
// this is Console Application
HWND hDesk = FindWindow(NULL, L"Program Manager");
HWND hDesk2 = FindWindowEx(hDesk, NULL, L"SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL);
HWND hListView = FindWindowEx(hDesk2, NULL, L"SysListView32", NULL);

int iconCount = (int)SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, NULL, NULL);

printf("컨트롤(Control) + F2\n");
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_CONTROL, VK_F2);

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
{
    PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001);
    switch (msg.message)
    {
    case WM_HOTKEY:
        if (msg.wParam == 1)
        {
            printf("ㅇㅋ 누름 (Hotkey Event)\n");
            int a = SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
            int b;
            int ms = GetTickCount();
            CreateDirectory(L"C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\new Folder", NULL);
            //SendMessage(hListView, LVM_REDRAWITEMS, 0, a+5);
            //SendMessage(hListView, LVM_UPDATE, a, 0);
            //SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_MKDIR, SHCNF_IDLIST| SHCNF_PATHW, L"C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop", NULL);
            while (true)
            {
                b = SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
                if (a != b) {
                    ms = GetTickCount() - ms;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Sleep(1);
            POINT mouse;
            GetCursorPos(&mouse);
            SendMessage(hListView, LVM_SETITEMPOSITION, b - 1, MAKEWPARAM(mouse.x, mouse.y));
            SendMessage(hListView, LVM_EDITLABEL, b - 1, 0);

        }

    }
}
```

I thought `CreateDirectory` was the problem and tried to create a directory using `NtCreateFile` (User Space / Ring3), but it is still slow.
The icon still appears slow on the desktop.

Is there WinAPI / DesktopAPI / COM / ATL for this?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do exactly. Do you want the "New..." menu appear? Or do you want to create a folder in the one given Shell' view? What's the relation with coordinates? You can use "Scriptable Shell Objects" (aka "Shell Objects for Scripting") to create a Folder using shell methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-newfolder

Comment: I can not speak English well. Sorry.
What I want to do is create a "desktop right click-> new-> folder" in C ++ code.
I have a CreateDirectory WinAPI, but it doesn't set the location of the desktop.
You can set the coordinates using SendMessage LVM_SETITEMPOSITION.
However, there is a delay due to CreateDirectory.
Is there any way to speed it up?
Or is there another way?

Comment: @Simon Mourier  I've also tried using Shell Object, but it still appears slow on the desktop.

Comment: Hi @mp662002, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it if it does help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that simulates what's the New... Folder menu does from a Console Application.

It opens a view on some folder and create a child folder in it, and enter name edit mode. It's using the Shell's [IFileOperation interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) and also [ATL's smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class?view=vs-2019) only for simplicity.

```
int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl;
    CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> newFolderPidl;
    CComPtr<IFileOperationProgressSink> sink;
    CComPtr<IFileOperation> fo;
    CComPtr<IShellItem> folder;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidls = { nullptr };
    CFileOperationProgressSink csink;

    // get some folder's PIDL
    HRESULT hr = SHParseDisplayName(L"c:\\temp", NULL, &pidl, 0, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      // open it and, for demo purposes here, selects nothing (pass a terminator PIDL)
      ITEMIDLIST idl = { 0 };
      pidls = { &idl };
      hr = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 1, &pidls, 0);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
        // get a Shell Item from this PIDL
        hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folder));
      }
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      // we want to operate on files and directory using Shell's API
      hr = fo.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
        csink.QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&sink));

        // create the new folder "New Folder", using the sink
        // we need a sink to be advised of what really is the new folder
        // we can't use the name we've passed
        // because it could have been changed like 'New Folder (2)' if there's already a 'New Folder', etc.
        hr = fo->NewItem(folder, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, L"New Folder", NULL, sink);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
          // commit
          hr = fo->PerformOperations();
        }
      }
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      // we want the new child's relative-to-the-parent PIDL
      CComPtr<IParentAndItem> pai;
      hr = csink.m_newItem->QueryInterface(&pai);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
        hr = pai->GetParentAndItem(NULL, NULL, &newFolderPidl);
      }
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      // now, select the new child and get into name-edit mode (from the parent again)
      pidls = { newFolderPidl };
      hr = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 1, &pidls, OFASI_EDIT);
    }
  }

  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}

// the sink. this implementation's only interested by PostNewItem
class CFileOperationProgressSink : public IFileOperationProgressSink
{
  LONG m_cRef;

public:
  CComPtr<IShellItem> m_newItem;

  CFileOperationProgressSink() : m_cRef(1)
  {
  }

  STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
  {
    static const QITAB qit[] =
    {
      QITABENT(CFileOperationProgressSink, IFileOperationProgressSink),
      { 0 },
    };
    return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
  }

  STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)() { return InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef); }
  STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)()
  {
    if (InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef))
      return m_cRef;

    delete this;
    return 0;
  }

  STDMETHOD(StartOperations)() { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(FinishOperations)(HRESULT hrResult) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PreRenameItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, LPCWSTR pszNewName) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PostRenameItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, LPCWSTR pszNewName, HRESULT hrRename, IShellItem* psiNewlyCreated) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PreMoveItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, IShellItem* psiDestinationFolder, LPCWSTR pszNewName) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PostMoveItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, IShellItem* psiDestinationFolder, LPCWSTR pszNewName, HRESULT hrMove, IShellItem* psiNewlyCreated) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PreCopyItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, IShellItem* psiDestinationFolder, LPCWSTR pszNewName) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PostCopyItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, IShellItem* psiDestinationFolder, LPCWSTR pszNewName, HRESULT hrCopy, IShellItem* psiNewlyCreated) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PreDeleteItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PostDeleteItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiItem, HRESULT hrDelete, IShellItem* psiNewlyCreated) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PreNewItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiDestinationFolder, LPCWSTR pszNewName) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PostNewItem)(DWORD dwFlags, IShellItem* psiDestinationFolder, LPCWSTR pszNewName, LPCWSTR pszTemplateName, DWORD dwFileAttributes, HRESULT hrNew, IShellItem* psiNewItem)
  {
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrNew))
    {
      psiNewItem->QueryInterface(&m_newItem);
    }
    return S_OK;
  }
  STDMETHOD(UpdateProgress)(UINT iWorkTotal, UINT iWorkSoFar) { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(ResetTimer)() { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(PauseTimer)() { return S_OK; };
  STDMETHOD(ResumeTimer)() { return S_OK; };
};
```